# Check if link contains query parameters or not

Tags: javascript

I want to check if links to a specific page contain query parameter / question mark.

If links to site exist & contain query parameter

//append parameters

Else if links to site exist & don't contain parameter

//add parameters

Here's what I've got to just check if that links exist - which works but doesn't consider if the link contains an existing (?)

```
var extDomain = "website.com";
var links = document.getElementsByTagName('a');

Array.prototype.forEach.call(links, function (link) {
if (link.href.indexOf(extDomain) >= 1)  {   
       link.href += '?foo=bar';}
   });
```

Comment: why don't you check that `?` exist or not

Answer (score 0):

You can check if a string includes a character using the includes method. For example:

```
"website.com/hello?asdf=asdf".includes("?") // returns boolean
```

If a url has a `?`, it has parameters.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.slice()` with parameter `-` and `.search` property of `a` element to perform logic

```
var extDomain = "website.com";
var links = document.getElementsByTagName('a');

Array.prototype.forEach.call(links, function (link) {
   if (link.href.indexOf(extDomain) >= 1 && link.href.slice(-1) !== "?"
      || !link.search && link.slice(-1) !== "?")  {   
       link.href += '?foo=bar';
   } 
   if (link.search && link.slice(-1) === "?") {
       link.href += 'foo=bar';
   }
   if (link.search.length) {
       link.href += '&foo=bar';
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
links.map(function(link) {
  if(link.indexOf('?')) {
    return link + '&someparam=1';
  } else {
    return link + '?someparam=1';
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Additionally to the other great answers, you might as well use [URL](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/URL/URL) and ask if `search` is no empty string. Although this is an experimental technology (according to MDN), it has support in all major browsers (expect, IE, of course, *rolling eyes*).

```js
var links = document.getElementsByTagName('a');

Array.prototype.slice.call(links).forEach(l => {
  if (new URL(l.href).search) {
    // URL contains query parameter
    console.log(l);
  }
});
```

```html
<a href="http://example.com?foo=bar">Foo</a>
<a href="http://example.com">Bar</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also verify using regex. Example:

```
hasQueryParams = new RegExp(/(\?.*)$/).test(link.href)
// returns true if link has ? char included
```

In your case we will have:

```
var extDomain = "website.com";
var links = document.getElementsByTagName('a');

Array.prototype.forEach.call(links, function (link) {
    if new RegExp(/(\?.*)$/).test(link.href) {
        link.href += '&foo=bar';
    }
    else {
        link.href += '?foo=bar';
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I just did this and test on my machine, it works cool.

```
<a href="website.com?param1=999">link 1</a>
            <a href="website.com?param2=9d99">link2</a>
            <a href="website.com">link 3</a>
            <a href="website.com">link 4</a>
            <a href="notwebsite.com">link 5</a>
            <a href="notwebsite.com?params=34">link 6</a>



     <script>
var extDomain = "website.com";
            var links = document.getElementsByTagName('a');

            Array.prototype.forEach.call(links, function (link) {
                if ((link.href.indexOf(extDomain) > 0) && (link.href.indexOf('?') === -1 ))  {
                    link.href = extDomain +'?foo=bar';
                    console.log('this does not have a parameter before==='+link.href);
                }else{
                    console.log('already has ? link === '+link.href);
                }
            });
</script>
```

Please try check on you machine

Comment: How might the following be considered to include checking the extDomain?

   link.href.indexOf('?')

Comment: That code check if the link has the domain name in your case 'website.com' and at the same time checked if the link has the ? Symbol which indicate that a parameter exist....if not exist it add the extdomain as website.com?foo=bar ....note that it only add it to d link if ? Doesn't exist. You can now replace the old link with d new one.

Comment: It doesn't appear to work when the link contains ? var links = document.getElementsByTagName('a');

Array.prototype.forEach.call(links, function (link) {
if ((link.href.indexOf(extDomain) >= 1) && (link.href.indexOf('?') !== 1 ))  { 
link.href = extDomain +'?foo=bar';      
       }
else {
link.href = extDomain +'&foo=bar';      

}
   });

Comment: this is tested and working fine, please try it and let me know if you want anything else to be added to it

Answer (score -1):

i usually solve it like this

```
if (link.href.indexOf(extDomain) >= 1)  { 

    var has_query = link.href.split('?').length === 2;

    if( !has_query ) link.href+='?x=0';

    link.href += '&foo=bar';
}
```